# How to get tweets between two specific dates?

Tags: python, selenium

i want to get tweets b/w two specific dates.what i need to add in this code? i made this crawaler to scrape the tweets and now i want tweets just b/w two dates

```
import csv

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



####################################################
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
base_url1=u"https://twitter.com/search?q="
query1=u"23gaming&src=typd" 
url1=base_url1 + query1
browser.get(url1)
body1=browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
csvfile=open("gaming file.csv" , 'wt' , newline='')
writer=csv.writer(csvfile)

for _ in range(10):
    body1.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

tweets=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('content')
for tweet in tweets:
    cswRow=[]
    print(tweet.text)
    cswRow.append(tweet.text.encode('utf-8'))
    writer.writerow(cswRow)
```

Comment: You made no attempt to solve this yourself? Look into the `datetime` library for python for stuff that might help you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without any attempt to accomplish this in Selenium it's hard for us to help you, but it seems like this may be better accomplished using the Twitter developer API.

The [Standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html) has a method to search for tweets within a time period by using the `since_id` and `until` parameters. You could just do something like

```
myBot.search.tweets.(q='search phrase', since_id=[date start], until=[date end])
```